How to chain an Axios response interceptor with axios-retry for GraphQL service handling throttling?
I'm working on an Axios response interceptor to handle responses from a GraphQL service that, in case of throttling, returns a 200 status code with the error details inside the response body. My goal is to detect this throttling error and modify the response by returning a 429 status code. I want to chain this with axios-retry so that the request is retried when throttling occurs.
I wrote the following code, but axios-retry is never triggered, even when the interceptor correctly detects the throttling error and returns a 429 status:
const axios = require("axios");
const axiosRetry = require("axios-retry").default;

const instance = axios.create();

axiosRetry(instance, {
  retries: 3,
  retryDelay: axiosRetry.exponentialDelay,
  retryCondition: (error) => {
    return axiosRetry.isNetworkOrIdempotentRequestError(error) || error.response?.status === 429;
  },
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    if (response.status === 200 && response.data.errors) {
      const throttledError = response.data.errors.find(
        (error) => error.extensions && error.extensions.code === "THROTTLED"
      );

      if (throttledError) {
        const error = new Error('Rate limited');
        error.response = {
          status: 429,
          data: 'Too Many Requests'
        };
        return Promise.reject(error);
      } 
    }
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

(async () => {
  try {
    await instance.post("http://127.0.0.1:3030/throttled");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error status", JSON.stringify(error));
  }
})();

I also tried moving the axiosRetry setup below the interceptor, but it didn't change the result. The error is caught, but axios-retry is not triggered, and no retries are attempted. Why is axios-retry not retrying the request when a 429 status is returned from the interceptor?
What changes do I need to make to ensure that retries occur when the service returns a throttling error?
